# Check if multiple strings serially exist in another string

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I check if any of the strings in an array exists in another string?

Like:

```
a = ['the', 'you']
b = ['is', 'are']
c = ['now', 'not']
str = "the game is now"
if "the" in str:
 print "the strings found in str"
else:
 print "the strings found in str"
```

Now I want to check if "you" is found in "a" after that "are" is found in "b" not before that. Any help, Please Dears ?

Comment: Off-topic: If you are new to Python I would recommend jumping on 3.X as 2.X will be discontinued.

Comment: Your question is unclear. "are" is in "b" only

Comment: Could you please make your question a bit more clear

Comment: @ Nuts Hi there! Sure! okay I am giving a more details. "your game is over" is a sentence. now I want to check if "the word "your" , "game" and "is" is present here and if the word "game" comes after "your" word and the word "is" is after the word "game". :)

Comment: use index to check its first appearing index and compare that?

Comment: @ Marcus.Aurelianus Yeap! Something like that! Comparing! can you help me with that dear, please? :)

Answer (score 0):

Can do that using regex.

```
import re

a = ['your', 'game', "is", "over"]
regex = ".+".join(a)
print(regex)
if re.match(regex, "your game my dear player is over"):
    print("It's over")
```

With indexes:

```
a = ['your', 'game', "is", "over"]

list_of_words = " game my dear player is over".split()
is_correct = True
for i, value in enumerate(a):
    if i < 1:
        continue
    if value not in list_of_words or a[i - 1] not in list_of_words:
        is_correct = False
        break
    if list_of_words.index(value) < list_of_words.index(a[i - 1]):
        is_correct = False
if is_correct:
    print("It's over")
```

Comment: @ Nuts I am trying with the Index one Dear! :)